# How to check dictionary items are present in the list ? PYTHON

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the dictionary :

```
data_portgroup = {"data_portgroup" : ["DataPortGroup1", "DataPortGroup2"]}
mgmt_portgroup = {"mgmt_portgroup" : ["MgmtPortGroup1", "MgmtPortGroup2"]}
trunk_portgroup = {"trunk_portgroup" : ["TrunkPortGroup1", "TrunkPortGroup2"]}
```

And I have a list :

```
portgroups = ["VM Network", 
"VMPortGroup1",
"DataPortGroup1",
"f7b64e53-cdb0-4bb6-b479-8c8aa6a5ab10",
"TrunkPortGroup1",
"dvSwitch-DVUplinks-232",
"MgmtPortGroup1",
"dvPortGroup",
"dvSwitchOVSvApp-DVUplinks-69",
"dvSwitchBootVMs-DVUplinks-61"
]
```

Now I want to check dictionary values are present in the list ?

Comment: You seem to have multiple dictionaries that you refer to as 'the dictionary', I assume you want to check all of them?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What is the expected output?

Comment: Yes ,  For each data_portgroup  "DataPortGroup1" is present in the list or not . In the same way will check next dictionary.

Comment: does all dict have single key associated with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension (pythonic way to construct lists) like in

```
found_in_data_portgroup  = [pg for pg in portgroups if pg in data_portgroup["data_portgroup"]]
found_in_mgmt_portgroup  = [pg for pg in portgroups if pg in mgmt_portgroup["mgmt_portgroup"]]
found_in_trunk_portgroup = [pg for pg in portgroups if pg in trunk_portgroup["trunk_portgroup"]]

print found_in_data_portgroup
print found_in_mgmt_portgroup
print found_in_trunk_portgroup
```

to obtain

```
['DataPortGroup1']
['MgmtPortGroup1']
['TrunkPortGroup1']
```

Comment: Excellent ! I was writing the comprehension but got the efficient answer within seconds.